# Why use event.currentTarget when I can just use the element itself?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

Say I want to add `rounded-circle` class to an image when I click on it:

```
const img = document.getElementById('my-image');
img.addEventListener('click', () => {
  event.currentTarget.classList.add('rounded-circle');
});
```

I've been taught to use `event.currentTarget` in order to select that image within the callback. However, since this image is already declared in the variable `img`, I can also do:

```
const img = document.getElementById('my-image');
img.addEventListener('click', () => {
  img.classList.add('rounded-circle');
});
```

So why use `event.currentTaget` instead of `img`? Is there a preferred way, and why?

Comment: When a function doesn’t refer to anything outside itself, it allows for *handwave* optimizations. But if using the global `event` this might be really old IE-memory-leak-related advice. You’ve been taught to use it by what?

Answer (score -1):

The currentTarget returns the element whose event listener triggered the event. in contrast to target which returns the element triggered the event. Another way to get the element whose event lsitener triggered, is through `this` keyword in event listener:

```
document.getElementById('my-image').addEventListener('click', function () => {
  this.classList.add('rounded-circle');
});
```